# FFT of frequency bands and limited amplitude modulation

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, feature-extraction, amplitude-modulation

In [this paper](https://dafx.de/paper-archive/2010/DAFx10/SeyerlehnerWidmerPohle_DAFx10_P31.pdf) they preprocess a cent spectrum of an audio file.
For comparison of audio files they create the Logarithmic Fluctuation Pattern(LFP)(p.3).
For this I have to use a FFT on each frequency band of a block and then only take into account the amplitude modulations up to 600 bpm. (See screenshot)

[image]
[image]

I want to implement this LFP into Python but I have no idea what to look for.
Can I just use a simple Python `np.fft()` on each block band?
What is meant with the amplitude modulation and the limitation of 600 bpm?

This is the only aspect of my work where I need this much insight and I tried to understand the amplitude modulation but it's seems to be pretty complicated.

Anyone can explain me what I have to do?